# Большие объёмы текста и БД: хранить текст строкой в базе данных или хранить там лишь ссылку на файл с текстом?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite, android-sqlite

**Дано:**

Положим надо хранить в в приложении большие объёмы текста (html код с новостыми статьями внутри).

**Вопрос:**

Хранить прямо в ячейке БД - нормально? Или это повлияет критично на производительность и вообще не приветствуется? Стоит ли перейти на вариант записи текста каждого в отдельный файл и хранения в БД только ссылок на них? Последнее вызывает сомнения в виду нужды в дополнительных действиях...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не думаю что могут быть какие либо проблемы с производительностью при хранении статей непосредственно в БД. SQLite вполне рассчитана на хранение больших текстов. Плюс появляется возможность полнотекстового поиска по всем статьям. Единственное от чего может просесть производительность это от частого обновления статей. Ну и возможно есть смысл хранить содержимое статей в отдельной таблице, дабы не дергать эти большие текстовые массивы лишний раз при работе со списками статей.

Comment: Спасибо) Как раз помышляю о доп. таблице для текстов)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите хранить большие объемы текста, то рекомендую вам воспользоваться документо-ориентированными базами данных типа `MongoDB` или `RavenDB`. Они были разработаны как раз для того, чтобы решать эти задачи.

Но если вы хотите развернуть базу на android, то sqlite будет лучшим, я бы даже сказал безальтернативным вариантом.

Документация говорит:

> SQLite will be happy to store a 500-million character string there

Ссылка на документацию: [тык](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9)

Как пользоваться sqlite на android можно почитать [тут](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: А их под `Android` можно пользовать? А то у меня и так `orm` обёртка над `SQLite` заюзана...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можно. Например с `RavenDB` можно общаться используя WebAPI

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вопрос только в том, хотите ли вы развернуть базу на андройде, или же вам нужна удаленная база.

Comment: БД на устройстве, удалённая не подходит)

Answer (score 1):

Особо это повлиять не должно, со ссылками может получиться дольше. А в идеале нужно написать тестовый код и протестировать в разных ситуациях, после чего выбрать оптимальное решение.

Comment: Т.е. нема общепринятой практики поведения в подобных случаях?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб почему же, есть, метод тыка называется) Лучше сначала напиши, увидишь, что недостаточно быстро работает, оптимизируй.

Answer (score 1):

Реляционные(SQL) базы данных, обычно нужны для двух вещей: контроль целостности данных и контроль доступа к ним. Но при этом вам придется смирится с тем что для работы с этими данными вам нужно будет совершать какие либо "телодвижения", и вот эти "телодвижения" как раз и могут сказаться и на производительности и на, например, на сопровождении... Если же вам не нужен контроль целостности или доступа или оба (а вы точно в этом уверены?), то в БД можно хранить ссылку. Но такая ситуация очень больно аукнеца, когда окажется что они все таки надо. Потому что обеспечить это "самописными" методами гораздо проблемней чем работать с базой данных.

P.S. Не скажу про noSQL - не работал.